# Hide iframe url

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, sqlserver

I am using a visualforce page and adding an apex tag:

```
<apex:page standardController="account"> 
  <apex:iframe src="a.com/embed/preview/f?theme=dark fullscreen" width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="0" scrolling="NO"/> 
</apex:page
```

I am trying to hide the URL from the visualforce page , Is it possible using standard functionality.

Comment: I don't quite understand. Can you post your visualforce and controller?

Comment: <apex:page standardController="account">
  <apex:iframe src="https://a.com/embed/preview/f?theme=dark fullscreen" width="100%" height="800px" frameborder="0" scrolling="NO"/>
   </apex:page>

Comment: can you explain with screen capture on what you are expecting ?

Comment: Are you trying to hide the URL from anyone that might look at the page source? Ultimately, iframes are html. (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) You can't hide stuff, and it's probably not a good idea to try, since hackers might just see it as a challenge.

Comment: You can't hide a URL that is embedded in HTML. Best I can recommend you is to obfuscate it by using a redirect service (like bit.ly) so somebody will have to hunt further down to get to it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1: URL Shortener

If hiding the [`apex:iframe`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_iframe.htm) URL from the resulting [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) in the client-side source code is sufficient, then you can use the [Bitly URL Shortener](https://bitly.com/) service to obfuscate the URL.

If the original URL is hosted on Salesforce.com, the resulting short URL will automatically use `sforce.co`:

```
https://sforce.co/XXXXXXX
```

If the original URL is not hosted on Salesforce.com, the resulting short URL will likely use `bit.ly`:

```
https://bit.ly/XXXXXXX
```

The problem with using this method is that, while the URL may be hidden in the client-side source code, in most browsers, a user can fairly easily open [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) content in a new window or tab (displaying the destination URL in the address bar).

Alternatively, a user may be able to monitor the network and view the resulting [`Location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) response header from the request to determine where the page has been redirected to, without having to leave the Visualforce page at all.

#### Option 2: External Proxy

A better way to hide the URL would be to run the target web page and all of its resources through a proxy on an external server and obfuscate the URL as part of the proxy service.

There are many web proxy sites like this that exist, but many of them come with an undesirable toolbar embedded in the destination web page to allow navigation to another site, or they are very slow, or they cause the sites to malfunction, or they are flatly rejected by Salesforce [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP):

> Refused to display 'https://www.hidemyass-freeproxy.com/proxy/en-ww/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' in a frame because an ancestor violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-ancestors https://www.hidemyass.com".

#### Conclusion:

The user experience will most likely be a better one (in many different ways) if you exercise transparency, and leave the [`iframe`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) URL unobscured.

If you must attempt to hide the origin of the content, consider using an external proxy to obfuscate the URL and its content, but know that this method is not bulletproof in the sense of privacy, and the origin of the web page can likely be determined by certain users in certain situations.

You must determine if the cost in user experience is worth the benefit in obscurity.